# Thumbnail images appearing stretched on mobile devices (Magento)

Tags: php, html, magento, magento-1.9

The thumbnails on my **Highlighted Products** carousel are appearing stretched on mobile devices. Does anyone know how I could correct this? This is a portion of my `highlights.phtml` file where the images are being displayed:

```
 <li class="item">
       <div class="product" >
            <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($product['url']) ?>">
                  <img src="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($product['image']) ?>">
            </a>
```

This issue also occurs on my **Related Products** carousel. Here's the portion of the Related.phtml file where the images get called:

```
<div class="product">
     <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"
         title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" class="product-image">
         <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail') ?>"
         alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>"/></a>
```

Comment: Add image in div background using css

Comment: Thanks @BhAvikGajjar. I'm new to Magento and web dev so not sure where to make the change you said :/

Comment: refer this link : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_background.asp

Comment: This is going to depend **a lot** on which theme you're using and the *product-image* class in the CSS (and which CSS file will depend on the theme)... Magento (1.x), by default, only resizes on width IIRC; see *System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Product Image* (you can also check the *./media/cache* directory). As an aside, Magento 1 is approaching end-of-life, you should be looking at migrating to M2.

Comment: Aside: *"I'm new to Magento and web dev"* ... if you're new to web dev, Magento is **NOT** the best place to start; I would say it's horrendously convoluted (if I was being polite) - and M2 is even worse to develop on.